# Using async/await and got "failed to execute 'json' on 'response' body stream is locked at eval" error

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
const repoBarGraph = async () => {
    d3.selectAll("#bar-vis > *").remove();
    d3.select(".main-vis-container > #tip").remove();

    const repoNames = await fetchRepos(userInputValue.value);
    const days = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ];
    const reposWeekCommits = await Promise.all(
      repoNames.map(async repoName => {
        const repoStats = await fetchRepoStats(userInputValue.value, repoName);
        let dayCommitArr = Array(7).fill(0);
        repoStats.map(repoStat => {
          repoStat.days.map((day, i) => (dayCommitArr[i] += day));
        });
        debugger;
        return dayCommitArr;
      })
    );

    let sumArr = Array(7).fill(0);
    reposWeekCommits.map(repoDayCommits =>
      repoDayCommits.map((repoDayCommit, i) => (sumArr[i] += repoDayCommit))
    );

    let barData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
      barData.push({ day: days[i], commits: sumArr[i] });
    }
    console.log(barData);
    ...
```

Whenever I try to run this code it gives me an unexpected end of JSON input. That is because of a "failed to execute 'json' on 'response' body stream is locked at eval" error. But I can't see where I'm using my promise more than once or how to fix it. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code for whichever `fetchRepos()` or `fetchRepoStats()` is rejecting with this error.  That is apparently where the problem is.  I have a guess that some code is not reading the entire response, but I'd need to see the code to know.

Comment: FYI, it is really misleading when you use `.map()` for side effect programming (e.g. not using the resulting array that `.map()` returns at all).  Please use `for/of` or `.forEach()` instead.